# SQL: Set conditional value based on another table, with a BETWEEN date criteria

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, between, ansi-sql

a bit new to SQL and did some searching online but couldn't find an answer.

The SQL database is a Snowflake DB, which I believe is a ANSI db.

I have a fact table as outlined below. Combinations of same Issue/UPC/Warehouse/Date can be possible, since a new record is added whenever a new issue is reported.

[image]

The exclude column is what I'm trying to figure out - it should be 'Y' if the combo of Issue/UPC/Warehouse and Date is in the Exclusion table, shown below.
[image]

The tricky part is that data is at the individual day level, but I want to exclude it if it falls within the range.

So here, only I-100/1234/China/5-5-2019 and I-324/1349/NewYork/6-1-2019 should be excluded, since they match values and date ranges in the Exclusion table.

I tried the below query but the SELECT for DATES BETWEEN is returning more than 1 record, and giving me this error `Single-row subquery returns more than one row.`

```
update "FactDetails" 
set "EXCLUDE" = 'Y'

where ("UPC","Warehouse", "Issue") in
    ("UPC","Warehouse", "Issue" from "Exclusions"
     where "PLANT_NUMBER" is not null
     and "ISSUE_CODE" is not null)

and "Date" between 
    (select "DATE_FROM" from "Exclusion"
     where "PLANT_NUMBER" is not null
     and "ISSUE_CODE" is not null) and
    (select "DATE_TO" from "Exclusion"
     where "PLANT_NUMBER" is not null
     and "ISSUE_CODE" is not null);
```

Another complexity is that the Exclusion table can have 'levels' to exclude by combinations of UPC/Issue/Warehouse. Warehouse is the most specific, and if just UPC, this covers the most data.
[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
update t
    set exclude = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where e.issue_code = t.issue_code and
                        e.upc = t.upc and
                        e.warehouse = t.warehouse and
                        t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
                 );
```

Comment: Thank you - would you be able to help me with this small bit of added complexity? The Exclusion table can be used in 3 levels, to exclude by UPC/Issue/Warehouse, by UPC/Issue, or by UPC. Ex: if the level is UPC, then all records for that UPC should be excluded in that date range, and Issue and Warehouse is null in the Exclusion table. I have provided a picture in the main post. I believe I can't just do the three hierarchies one after another, because some data will be excluded that shouldn't be.

Comment: @xii  . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  You should ask a new question with a more complete description of the exclusion table along with appropriate sample data and desired results.  If you change the question here, you will invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes.

Comment: Just posted question, link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442059/sql-set-conditional-value-based-on-varying-criteria-in-another-table