# SQL: Set conditional value based on varying criteria in another table

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ansi-sql

A bit new to SQL - the db is Snowflake, which I believe is ANSI

Main table shown below. Combinations of same Issue/UPC/Warehouse/Date can be possible, since a new record is added whenever a new issue is reported. Other columns exist, but should not affect this question

[image]

The exclude column is what I'm trying to figure out - it should be 'Y' if the desired combination of Issue/UPC/Warehouse and Date is in the Exclusion table, shown below.

[image]

The tricky part is the LEVEL column, defining if a UPC/Issue/Warehouse combination must match, or just UPC/Issue, or just UPC. Also, the records in the main table must fall within the Date range to be excluded.

Visually, expected result is this

[image]

This solution works for just one level (Issue/UPC/Warehouse), but I can't figure out how to do the other two without overlap and the possibility of excluding records on accident.

```
update t
set exclude = 'Y'
where exists (select 1
              from exclusions e
              where e.issue_code = t.issue_code and
              e.upc = t.upc and
              e.warehouse = t.warehouse and
              t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to);
```

Comment: you use case is a bit complicated, but it sounds like you just need a case statement.
There's plenty of documentation out there on how to do that, and it should all apply to Snowflake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442524/13472370) has covered the right approach to take, using the [`CASE` conditional expression](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html), but ensure that your query also incorporates the level check into each condition explicitly. Here's a verbose example:

```sql
update t
set exclude = case
    when exists(
        select 1
        from exclusions e
        where 
                e.warehouse = t.warehouse
            and e.upc = t.upc
            and e.issue_code = t.issue_code
            and t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
            and e.level = 'UPC/ISSUE/WAREHOUSE'
    ) then 'Y'
    when exists(
        select 1
        from exclusions e
        where 
                e.issue_code = t.issue_code
            and e.upc = t.upc
            and t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
            and e.level = 'UPC/ISSUE'
    ) then 'Y'
    when exists(
        select 1
        from exclusions e
        where 
                e.upc = t.upc
            and t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
            and e.level = 'UPC'
    ) then 'Y'
    else ''
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not following what your solution is missing, but You can handle multiple different situations/outputs for the column with a case statement. Only the first one that matches will apply so it can prevent overlap.

Something like this:

```
update t
set exclude = CASE
    WHEN EXISTS 
        (select 1
         from exclusions e
         where e.issue_code = t.issue_code and
             e.upc = t.upc and
             e.warehouse = t.warehouse and
             t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
        ) THEN 'Y'
    WHEN --Other situation where it meets your criteria
        THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END
;
```

You could also use this to invert your logic to specify 'N' situations and default to 'Y' if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I ignore the `level` column, then I can just use `null` to see if there is a match.  If that suffices, then:

```
update t
    set exclude = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where (e.issue_code = t.issue_code or e.issue_code is null) and
                        (e.upc = t.upc or e.upc is null) and
                        (e.warehouse = t.warehouse or e.warehouse is null) and
                        t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
                 );
```

You *can* use the `level` column as well (I think the above is clearer).  Something like this:

```
update t
    set exclude = 'Y'
    where exists (select 1
                  from exclusions e
                  where (e.issue_code = t.issue_code or e.level not like '%ISSUE%') and
                        (e.upc = t.upc or e.level not like '%UPC%') and
                        (e.warehouse = t.warehouse or e.level like '%WAREHOUSE%') and
                        t.date between e.date_from and e.date_to
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what David said, what you need is an update with case statement. 
Be bit careful with case statement - only the first criteria that is met will be executed. 
so code for the most common case first, then next most common .. to finally the least common criteria.